# Mariadb Auto Increment get reset after deleting all records

Tags: mysql, mariadb, auto-increment

When I delete all records from my mysql table, the auto increment counter gets reset to 0. My application logic is migrating records from MySQL to other analytic engine and then deleting migrated records from MySQL. Analytic engine manages records with same primary key as MySQL, hence when MySQL resets the counter, I am getting duplicate key error in my analytic engine. I want Mysql to preserve the auto_increment, even when I delete all records from my database.

```
alter table test auto_increment = 100;
```

I can execute above query to preserve auto_increment after deleting my records, but If I restart MySQL, this counter again get reset to default 0.

I know this is an expected behavior from MySQL. But I am looking for a workaround to overcome it.

I am using mariadb instead of mysql. Please see auto_increment counter before and after restart.

```
MariaDB [MY_DB]> SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `MY_DB` WHERE `name` LIKE 'test' ;
+---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name    | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------+
| test | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    6 |           2730 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              7 | 2017-05-22 23:38:06 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_bin  |     NULL |                |         |
+---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [MY_DB]> select max(id) from test;
+---------------+
| max(id) |
+---------------+
|             6 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [MY_DB]> delete from test where id in (1,2,3,4,5,6);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [MY_DB]> SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `MY_DB` WHERE `name` LIKE 'test' ;
+---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name    | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------+
| test | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              7 | 2017-05-22 23:38:06 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_bin  |     NULL |                |         |
+---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [MY_DB]> exit
Bye
root@atd-3000:~# systemctl restart mariadb
root@atd-3000:~# mysql -p***** MY_DB;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 57
Server version: 10.1.17-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [MY_DB]> SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `MY_DB` WHERE `name` LIKE 'test' ;
+---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name    | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------+
| test | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2017-05-22 23:38:06 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_bin  |     NULL |                |         |
+---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

Comment: DELETE query will not reset auto_increment id while TRUNCATE will

Comment: Post the query which you are using to delete all migrated rows

Comment: You are right. But if you restart mysql, then it will reset the auto_increment counter back to 1.

Below is the delete query I am using:

`Delete from test where id in (1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: No it won't!?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As innodb is memory based counter, Innodb will not preserve the auto_increment value. I have implemented a workaround to solve my solution:

1. After deleting the records from Mariadb, I am preserving the max ID in other table.
2. After mariadb service start, in postinit, I am setting the auto_increment counter for table after reading max ID. Here I check if auto_increment counter is already greater than the MAX ID I have, then I am not updating it. If it's less than I update the counter.

Hope it will help other folks who are facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, truncate query first deletes the table entirely & then creates a blank table... Since it is a totally new table now, auto_increment id is reset to 1..

On the other hand, a drop query only deletes the table & doesn't create a new one; so the auto-increment id remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE` will not reset `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but `TRUNCATE` will, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: You are right. But if you restart mysql, then it will reset the auto_increment counter back to 1.

Comment: Because auto_increment is memory based counter. Innodb engine executed `MAX(id)` to get auto_increment. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html